# quit() using Tkinter not working while executing as an app using py2app. However it works when I run it a python script

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter, py2app

1. I have imported sys
2. I have tried using sys.quit, again works when I run it as a python script but not as an app.
3. I have also tried calling root.destroy() inside the app_exit function

context: I have a button called exit which calls an app_exit function which just calls the quit function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python `quit()` and `exit()` functions are meant to be used in the REPL only. You need to use `sys.exit()` or `raise SystemExit`.